# Python: Use a loop to calculate the standard deviation of the values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate standard deviation based on values from a list, but I am receiving errors:

```
def mean(list):
    return sum(list)/len(list)

std_deviation = (sum([(list - mean(list)) ** 2 for number in list]) / (len(list) - 1)**(1/2)

print(std_deviation)
```

Comment: What is `list - mean(list)` meant to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if your goal is to learn or to solve the problem; if it's the latter look into the `statistics` module (especially `statistics.stdev`).

Comment: list - mean(list) is within the standard deviation formula X - mean(X)

Comment: the goal is not to use any functions such as statistics

Comment: You mean x_i - mean(X), i.e. a single element out of the list, `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Your parantheses are set wrong, and instead of `list - mean(list)`, you'll want `number - mean(list)`

Fixed version (without the name `list`, because it is a builtin):

```
def mean(values):
    return sum(values)/len(values)

my_list = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,8]

std_deviation = (1/(len(my_list) - 1) * sum((number - mean(my_list))**2 for number in my_list))**.5
print(std_deviation)  # prints 2.2519832529192065
```

Comment: This gives an "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" error. Any other idea?

Comment: the code provided by @L3viathan actually works. can you provide your testcase ?

Comment: @PeterWood I changed it in `mean`, but I want to keep the names seperate to differentiate the bound names in the function from the "external" name.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyList = [1,2,3,4,5]
mean = sum(MyList)/len(MyList)
stddev = sum([((i - mean)**2/len(MyList))**0.5 for i in MyList])
print(stddev)
```

[Python - List Comprehension](https://alphacodingskills.com/python/pages/python-list-comprehension.php)